# How to Display a single Date in Google Data Studio?

Tags: date, looker-studio

I want to display a single date dynamically in Google Data Studio. e.g. I want to display last Monday's date whatever it was e.g. `09-11-2020` and it would change to `16-11-2020` as the Monday `16-11-2020` would pass and so on.

I have a connection with BigQuery and I can connect from there to bring the date dynamically from BigQuery as:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 day), WEEK(MONDAY)) as coming_monday
```

&

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) as last_monday
```

So calculating dates isn't a problem as they are being received in Google Data Studio, however, I could not display them appropriately using any of the Google Data Studio tools like Text, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates can currently be displayed in Google Data Studio [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479); in addition, the [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in the question could be recreated by copy-pasting the below into the respective [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479), aggregating by [`MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583208) or [`MIN`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583210) (which would display the same Date in this scenario) and then setting the **Type** to `Date` (Default: `Date & Time`):

### 1) Coming_Monday

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), ISOWEEK)
```

### 2) Last_Monday

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), ISOWEEK)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/56442eab-ba2d-4deb-ad9a-206c3222d173) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It cannot set single dynamic value with straightforward way as text in GDS now.

But, you can use normal **Table** tool of GDS with single row, and it will show as single dynamic value that you need. **Scorecard** can also be used.

Here is how-to of using **Table**.

1. Under **Data** menu, set the date column that you want to display in *Dimension*, and do not set *Metric*. Also, choose *Rows per page* as **1**.
2. Under **Style** menu, uncheck the *Show header* checkbox, *Rows numbers* checkbox and *Shows pagination* checkbox.

[image: Edit view]

When you view the report, it will show as text.
[image: When view the report]